# SQL select rows based on range of numbers which are part of a long text column

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have the following data in an Oracle SQL DB:

```
create table test_tbl(userid varchar2(10) not null, username varchar2(50), employment_data varchar2(500));
insert into test_tbl(userid, username, employment_data) values
(1, 'jsmith', 'Microsoft-Programmer-2000-April 15,Google-Tester-2002-March 3,Apple-Manager-2008-October 29');
insert into test_tbl(userid, username, employment_data) values
(2, 'mblack', 'Facebook-Tester-2002-May 12');
insert into test_tbl(userid, username, employment_data) values
(3, 'fnlee', 'Apple-Builder-1998-June 2,Google-Tester-2004-July 4');
insert into test_tbl(userid, username, employment_data) values
(4, 'jstone', 'Microsoft-Manager-2002-July 1');
insert into test_tbl(userid, username, employment_data) values
(5, 'msfeng', 'Microsoft-Tester-1998-May 12,Facebook-Programmer-2001-January 23,Microsoft-Manager-2005-May 21');
insert into test_tbl(userid, username, employment_data) values
(6, 'jdoe', null);
```

I can have the hyphen and comma changed to a different separator, but the contents of the employment_data column would always need to be a [comma/ some other delimiter] separated list of [hyphen/ some other delimiter] separated lists containing company,position,year hired,month hired.

I want to get the userids of all people who, in a given range of years, where hired to work at a certain company. 
Example inputs and desired outputs:

- input: Facebook, 1995, 2001 ---> output: 5
- input: Facebook, 2000, 2004 ---> output: 2, 5
- input: Microsoft, 1996, 2009 ---> output: 1, 4, 5
- input: Microsoft, 2001, 2003 ---> output: 4

I tried using `XMLTABLE` but it didn't know how to handle the spaces.

I also tried `REGEXP_SUBSTR` this time with more success, but I still couldn't get it to work they way I wanted. Also, this required me to use a `WITH` clause which would be a problem due to the way the query is being built in code, the explanation of which is a long story but you'll have to take my word for it ;)

Thanks

Comment: Stop right there.  You are storing the employment history as a comma separated string.  To make matters worse, it isn't data from what should be a single column, it's from _multiple_ columns, because you have both the company name and date in there as well.  Please read about **normalizing** your data.

Comment: I know the scheme is far from being optimal, but that's what I have to work with :(

Comment: Why do you have to put up with this, unless maybe this is an assignment?

Comment: The data arrives like this. I thought of splitting it up using `XMLTABLE` to make it more sensible, but that didn't work :(

Comment: My suggestion is to scrub this data using something like Java or C# before bringing it into your database.  If someone crashes your party and leaves pizza face down on your carpet, you shouldn't be the one cleaning it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This complex task should be split into smaller steps.
The best way to demostrate the steps is to build the query using `WITH` clause.

When you understand the steps you can easily convert the query into a nested one according to your requirements.

```
with commas as (
  select t.*, regexp_substr(t.employment_data, '(^|,)([^,]+)',1,level,'',2) job
  from test_tbl t
  connect by prior dbms_random.value() is not null 
      and prior userid=userid 
      and regexp_substr(t.employment_data, '(^|,)([^,]+)',1,level,'',2) is not null
)
, hyphens as (
  select t.*
    , regexp_substr(t.job, '^\s*(.+?)\s*-\s*(.+?)\s*-(\d{4})-(.+)$', 1, 1, '', 1) company
    , regexp_substr(job, '^\s*(.+?)\s*-\s*(.+?)\s*-(\d{4})-(.+)$', 1, 1, '', 2) title
    , to_number(regexp_substr(job, '^\s*(.+?)\s*-\s*(.+?)\s*-(\d{4})-(.+)$', 1, 1, '', 3), '9999') year
    , regexp_substr(job, '^\s*(.+?)\s*-\s*(.+?)\s*-(\d{4})-(.+)$', 1, 1, '', 4) day_month
  from commas t
)
, filters as (
  select 1 id, 'Facebook' company, 1995 start_year, 2001 end_year from dual union all
  select 2, 'Facebook', 2000, 2004 from dual union all
  select 3, 'Microsoft', 1996, 2009 from dual union all
  select 4, 'Microsoft', 2001, 2003 from dual 
)
, dst as (
  select distinct f.company,f.start_year,f.end_year,t.userid
  from hyphens t join filters f 
    on t.company=f.company and t.year >=f.start_year and t.year <=f.end_year
)
select t.company, t.start_year, t.end_year, listagg(t.userid, ',') within group(order by t.userid) userids
from dst t 
group by t.company,t.start_year,t.end_year
order by t.company,t.start_year,t.end_year
```

The explanation:

First we split `employment_data` field on commas and produce `commas` CTE. 
We use a hierarchical query and `regexp_substr` with level for that. Note that we use dummy `prior dbms_random.value()` check to prevent ORA-01436 'connect by' loop error.
Results are put in the `job` field.

Then we extract needed fields from the `job`, splitting on hyphens and produce `hyphens` CTE.
We use `regexp_substr`, and it is straightforward. We take care of excess whitespace by using `\s*`.

After that we define filters. They could have been put on the top of the query, that does not matter.

By this moment we have the `hyphens` CTE that holds `company`, `year`, `userid` necessary for filtering.
Next we match these fields against filters and produce `dst` CTE.

And in the last select, we use listagg to concatenate unique matching ids and output resulting `userids` field.

And the results are:

```
COMPANY    START_YEAR  END_YEAR  USERIDS  
---------- ----------- --------- -------- 
Facebook   1995        2001      5        
Facebook   2000        2004      2,5      
Microsoft  1996        2009      1,4,5    
Microsoft  2001        2003      4
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a regex have a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm)

The REGEX_SUBSTR will be to much, you need to narrow down the possibilities as far as possible, so REGEX_LIKE could be used, the expression will probably turn out something like this:

```
^(company_name_you_searchfor)-[A-Za-z]*-(2000|2001|2002|2003|2004).*
```

Another option is you query with two regex's using REGEXP_INSTR for both. The first for the company the second for the year

Last I can think of the [INSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm#OLADM564) function

Comment: Thanks - but I may have multiple values in one row. e.g. userid 1 which was hired to work for 3 different companies over the years, or userid 5 who has data for being hired 3 times, 2 of which in Microsoft. I need to extract the year for all appearances of Microsoft, and only for those. Unless I'm misunderstanding REGEX_LIKE, that would not give me what I want (will only return one (probably the first) occurrence of 'Microsoft-')